# MVC3 project build fails because of web.config in obj folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, deployment

I have `<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>` setup in my project files.

Now when I do deployment the first time I get files in `obj\release\package\packagetmp`. Every subsequent build after this results in a faild build.

```
Web -> C:\Projects\ProjectX\Web\bin\ProjectX.Web.dll
C:\Projects\ProjectX\Web\obj\release\package\packagetmp\web.config(64): 
error ASPCONFIG: It is an error to use a section registered as 
allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  
This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an 
application in IIS.
------ Skipped Publish: Project Web, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
```

Now if delete the `obj` folder, I can build fine.

This is rather frustrating to have any build fail after I publish until I manually delete the `obj` folder. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add this to the .csproj file:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">
  <RemoveDir Directories="$(IntermediateOutputPath)" />
</Target>
```

Seems to delete the files in obj\Release but not the folder itself, at least on my machine.

Comment: It would be better to use `Condition="$(MvcBuildViews) == 'True'"` as the condition, in case you enable this feature for configurations other than release, as I have done.

Answer (score 5):

This problem occurs because MvcBuildViews conflicts with Web Deploy packaging. I got the idea for this solution from http://www.zvolkov.com/clog/2011/02/16/asp-net-razor-lessons-learned/ :

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageDependsOn Condition="'$(DeployOnBuild)'=='true'">
      CleanWebsitesPackage;
      CleanWebsitesPackageTempDir;
      CleanWebsitesTransformParametersFiles;
      MvcBuildViews;
      $(PackageDependsOn)
    </PackageDependsOn>
    <BuildDependsOn Condition="'$(DeployOnBuild)'!='true'">
      $(BuildDependsOn);
      MvcBuildViews
    </BuildDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="MvcBuildViews" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
    <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
  </Target>
```

Now AspNetCompiler will run before packaging. This works nicely with the msbuild /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployTarget=Package approach.

Comment: candrews answer is for VS 2010 and worked brilliantly. For VS2012, use this:
`<PropertyGroup> 
  <PackageDependsOn Condition="'$(DeployOnBuild)'=='true'"> CleanWebsitesPackage; CleanWebsitesWPPAllFilesInSingleFolder; CleanWebPublishPipelineIntermediateOutput; MvcBuildViews; $(PackageDependsOn) </PackageDependsOn> <BuildDependsOn Condition="'$(DeployOnBuild)'!='true'"> $(BuildDependsOn); MvcBuildViews </BuildDependsOn> 
</PropertyGroup>`

Comment: @danmiser: thanks! Yours seems to be the only permutation that works for VS2012.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with MVC when you enable the build MVC views feature. Hopefully they get it fixed in the next version.

In the mean time, you can run the "Clean Solution" operation to clear out the obj folder instead of doing it manually. The downside is, your entire solution will be rebuilt every time.

Another option that I haven't done, but have considered if my project gets any bigger, is a pre-compile step in the MVC project to remove the web.config from obj\

Comment: Clean doesn't seem to remove the package folder from obj. Hmm I guess the post build operation might be the only option.